# How can I install an old emulator image?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

My app is affected by a bug that is only present on certain builds of Android. Unfortunately, the bug is missing from the emulator images that are currently available through SDK Manager.

For example, I have revision 8 of the Android 10 emulator image installed, but the bug might only be present on revision 4.

How can I install an older revision of one of the emulator images, such as revision 4 of the Android 10 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this [page](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/AndroidSystemImages) or [this one](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/GoogleAPIaddonSystemImages) to download the images, it's not official but works; i've used in the past.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686444/android-studio-manually-download-system-image-for-emulator) is how to install them.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like you can also copy the download links URLs from that page, such as https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-R_r01.zip or https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-30_r05.zip, and tweak the revision numbers to get the exact revision needed

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that.