# Is there a way to use a personally customized system image in the Android Studio emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-automotive

I have system image, vendor image, etc. I have customized configuration files used in Android studio virtual device(automotive) sdk. However, if you proceed in the order based on these files, it will not be confirmed when creating a virtual device, and as a result, you cannnot a virtual device with your customized system image, etc. files.

So, could you please let me know if there any other method or if there is something I am doing wrong? PLEASE...

*PS: It was created and proceeded with **android automotive**, so please refer to it.

```
1.Extract the zipped file.
2.Copy extracted folder e.g.: x86.
3.Find the android-sdk folder. It is located at C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
4.Find the folder system-images. Create system-images if it doesn't exist.
5.Create subfolders within system-images. E.g.: system-images/android-27
6.Check in link, if it has google_apis or google_apis_playstore:
7.Paste within google_apis if link has google_apis or Paste it in google_apis_playstore folder.
8.The Complete path of system image file 
9.Restart Android Studio and the system image should be selectable.
```

Links to the methods above: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67890868/22366714)

Everyone must be busy, but if you know a method, please share it. (_ _)

[image]

As in the attached picture above, is there a way to refer to my customized system image, vendor image, etc... in the place where the system image is selected?

In addition, I configured and inserted files such as my system image through the path below, but they were not referenced. Also, if you replace and execute only my system image in the sdk file of another emulator that has already been created normally, the emulator cannot be run with a process termination error.

`C:` \ `Users` \ `KKM` \ `AppData` \  `Local` \ `Android` \ `Sdk` \ `system-images` \ `android-31` \ `mySystem(personally created)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.