# Visual Studio 2022 - How to install offline image for Android Device Manager

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-sdk-manager, android-device-manager

I'm trying to install an android Device in Visual studio Android device Manager and my internet is super slow so I have to obtain the image from elsewhere and install it offline.

I could not find and resources for this but it should be possible.

I downloaded and extracted the API 33 version image as per this post

[android studio - manually download system image for emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686444/android-studio-manually-download-system-image-for-emulator)

and I can see it's installed in the android SDK manager but the android device manager tries to download it again.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact image path you have manually copied from the other PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by following the exact steps in the link provided.
I had to delete the image and press the New button again. if the text "A new Device Image will be downloaded" is Not displayed it means the path copy is successful.
[image]